# My cam fell down - Dark Image

Tags: nikon, equipment-damage

My Nikon 7100 fell down today and since then the image is darker. First I thought it was from the lens (Nikkor 18-200mm), but I put my second lens, a prime lens 50mm F1.8 on, and the picture is still dark.

Comment: OK. What's your question?

Comment: Let's all assume that the OP wants to revert to the situation where the image is not darker than it should be. Are you talking about the image in the viewfinder, on the LCD display, or the images stored to the memory card? What settings are you using now? Are these the same settings that you always use? What have you tried to fix the issue?

Comment: The OP broke their camera, there isn't a question here...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't much of a question. The only thing to do is get it repaired. It could be  alignment, I would take it to an authorised Nikon service centre